# Importing Python egg module to Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am building a system on Google App Engine which uses ideone module which is a pure module in egg file. When i try to import it, the GAE says they cannot access the module:

```
[Errno 13] file not accessible: 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\ideone-0.1.4-py2.7.egg'
```

I have tried to put the egg in the project root and include the `__init__.py` but it still does not work , any idea to solve it?

The ideone module has dependency to module `suds-0.4-py2.7.egg`

Comment: `C:` ? I'm pretty sure Google App Engine doesn't run Windows. Or are you having problems getting it to work on your own computer?

Comment: no its fine with Windows, the problem is that GAE doesnot allow accessing zip package, the solution maybe we change the os path but I dont know how

Answer (score 1):

Extract the ideone directory from the egg, and put it in your app's main directory so you have `ideone/__init__.py`. Then you can `import ideone`.

Comment: but it has dependencies, if i do it that way, it breaks my project.

Comment: All of those dependencies must be included in your project directory.